# This protocol is vulnerable, but why?

Tags: encryption, authentication

I know that the following authentication protocol is vulnerable, but I can't understand why.

```
A and B share a secret key K (64 bits) 
R1 and R2 are two 64 bit numbers 

A-->B: I am A 
B-->A: R1 
A-->B: Hash((K+R1) mod 2^64), R2 
B-->A: Hash((K+R2) mod 2^63)
```

My thinking is that the two hashes don't line up, but I don't know that that would make this protocol have a major vulnerability.

Comment: I can see that Bob doesn't identify himself, Alice identifies herself and communicates the key (though hashed) to an unidentified party, who then sends it back. If Alice was communicating with Malory, Mal could spoof Bob.

Comment: If they share a key, can't they simply use that (under hash) for authentication?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do here!

Comment: Maybe better on crypto.se?

Answer (score 1):

Most obviously, it's subject to replay.

Mallory can sit on the line and keep watching authentications R1 and recording Hash((K+R1) mod 2^64).  Any time an old R1 appears, she can reuse the hash she saw earlier.

Similarly, if R2 appears that was seen earlier as an R1, she has a 50% chance that Hash((K+R2) mod 2^63) will be the same (i.e. if (K+R2) mod 2^64 has a most significant bit of 0).

Answer (score 1):

Keyed hashes have known attacks, for example H(m|K), H(K|m), H(K|m|K) all have some attacks that at least weakens them. HMAC is standard way to go that solves a lot of attacks which has the simplified form of H( K| H(K|m) ), the double hashing being key.

You can search more about HMAC and hash based message authentication but the point is that it is not that simple to come up with your own authentication algorithm unless you are a cryptographer that knows what they are doing.

64 bit keys are also small, it is advised to use bigger keys. It is also not clear what is the hashing algorithm used, not all are equal. The R1, R2 I assume are random.

Apart from that this is a basic authentication technique so if you were to use HMAC and bigger keys I wouldn't see any issue. I am also not so much an expert to say how vulnerable it, it would be interesting to share why you think it is vulnerable in the first place.

The replay attack mentioned is valid, though it depends how likely it is to get the same random, shouldn't be likely if you use a good random generator.